# Django Localization: How to Use a Non-English Language as 'Translate-From' Language

Tags: django

The problem is: if I set the English language as the primary language ( **LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en'** ) then all works fine. If we request the site from a browser with an English locale we see the English variant and analogically for a browser with a Russian locale.

But if I set **LANGUAGE_CODE = 'ru'** then we see the Russian variant in any case.

So why the English language is default and used by Django as msgid?

Please see the settings of my project below.

---

In my **settings.py** I try to set not English language as primary language:

```
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'ru'
LANGUAGES = ( ( 'en', "English", ), ( 'ru', "Russian", ), )
```

Then I have en/LC_MESSAGES/django.po:

```
msgid "SITE_MAIN_TITLE"
msgstr "D'argent: Cosmetics, Hair Care, Parfume"
```

And ru/LC_MESSAGES/django.po:

```
msgid "SITE_MAIN_TITLE"
msgstr "D'argent – косметика, средства по уходу за волосами, парфюмерия"
```

In template HTML:

```
...
<title>{% block title %}{% trans "SITE_MAIN_TITLE" %}{% endblock %}</title>
...
```

Comment: Which language translator(package) you are using?

Comment: The value in msgid reflects the value inside the trans tag, so  `{% trans "SITE_MAIN_TITLE" %}` will allways generate translation files with `msgid "SITE_MAIN_TITLE"`. What exactly is the problem after setting `LANGUAGE_CODE = 'ru'`?

Comment: @Secator The problem is that Django only works with ru/LC_MESSAGES/django.po when we set up LANGUAGE_CODE = 'ru' even if a current language of http client is English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IF you use this 'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware' middleware.

https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/utils/translation/trans_real.py#L366

see get_language_from_request function. Understand how to choose default language code. 
May be never used that settings.LANGUAGE_CODE ;).